How to apply hover effect to parent elements by accessing child elements?
                     <NestedMenuItem
                        label={client.type}
                        key={client.id}
                        parentMenuOpen={openClientGallery}
                        className="clients-MenuItem subMenuhover"
                        rightIcon={<ArrowRightIcon />}
                        sx={theme.nestedAndSimpleMenuitems}
                        data-testid="nestedMenuItem"
                       
                      >
                        {client.subMenu?.map((child) => (
                          <Box key={child.id}
                            className="subMenuhover"
                          >

                          <MenuItem
                            key={child.id}
                            onClick={() => {
                              handleMenuItemClick(child);
                            }}
                            id="subMenuItems"
                            data-testid="subMenuItems"
                          >
                            <Typography>{child.type}</Typography>
                          </MenuItem>
                          </Box>
                        ))}
                      </NestedMenuItem>
                    </Box>
                  );
                } else {
                  return (
                    <Box key={client.id}>
                      <MenuItem
                        key={client.id}
                        onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick(client)}
                        className="clients-MenuItem"
                        sx={theme.nestedAndSimpleMenuitems}
                        data-testid="nestedAndSimpleMenuitems"
                      >
                        <Typography data-testid="client">
                          {client.type}
                        </Typography>
                      </MenuItem>
                    </Box>

My Client Gallery array snippet-
export const clientGallery = [
{
id: 1,
type: "Approvals",
flag: true,
  subMenu: [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: "Approvals",
      path: "/homepage"
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      type: "Global Queue",
      path: "/homepage"
    },

    {
      id: 3,
      type: "Issuing Banks",
      path: "/homepage"
    },
  ],
},

{
  id: 2,
  type: "Client Information",
  flag: false,
  path: "/homepage"
},

]
package which I'm using for sub dropdown on hover - mui-nested-menu
My dropdown image
I'm opening a dropdown on click and some sub dropdowns on hover effect. When I hover over parent level menu items, whose flag is true, a background color effect is visible and a sub dropdown is
displayed. But when I go to sub dropdown that hover effect of parent menu item disappears. I want to keep it as it is. Until and unless I go any other parent level menuitem or go out side of the main menu.

Question is poorly formatted, too broad and unclear
